# JEditorPane setText remembers some tags

Tags: java, jeditorpane

I have strange problem with JEditorPane. I am using the same component for showing selected note. Problem is that some tags from first note is not removed when setText() method for second note is executed.

You may reproduce problem by code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JEditorPane editor=new JEditorPane();

    editor.setContentType("text/html");

    String html="<map name=\"map\">\n" +
            "<area shape=\"rect\" href=\"http://www.test.com/index.php\" target=\"_blank\" coords=\"8, 171, 141, 195\"></area>" +
            "</map>"
            + "<p>1111</p>";

    editor.setText(html); // first note

    editor.setText("<p>2222</p>"); // second note

    System.out.println(editor.getText());
}
```

Result for this code is:

```
<html>
  <head>   
  </head>
  <body>
    <map name="map">
      <area coords="8, 171, 141, 195" href="http://www.test.com/index.php" target="_blank" shape="rect"></area>
    </map>
    <p>
      2222
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

<map> and <area> tags from first note are still in JEditorPane when second note is set.

What is the problem? How to use setText method to remove all previous HTML content?

Thanks.

Edit:

I found workaround for this problem. It is ugly, but it works.

```
editor.setText(html);

editor.setContentType("text/plain");
editor.setContentType("text/html");

editor.setText("<p>2222</p>");
```

Comment: That's odd. Which version of java/jvm are you using? What you're reporting here is a bug.

Comment: I am using Java 1.7.0_51